# How to store user data from Html form?

Tags: html, forms

I have created a simple 2 input fields form ( name , number )

What I'm looking for is when user fills that up the data stores somewhere online in empty page/ or text file anywhere where I can reach out easily , Note: only I will be seeing that data so I don't care about it being look bad and not fancy, all I need is to be able to see the data.

I tried using MySQL database from infinityfree, it's only connecting my form to database but not entering the data into the table

Please tell me an easy way to store and see user data ? Without MySQL database and mail()

Answer (score 0):

Wich Language are you using?

PHP? nodeJS ?

MySql works with Querys so after connect you have to make a "Insert" query.

Other ways you can Store Data in Text File, like here (PHP) https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: Yes I did that , Insert into table name (  fields1 , field2 ) Values ( $value1 , $value2 )

Comment: Hm I dont know than. Is there any MySQL Error ect?

Comment: No, no errors it just takes me to a blank page , anyways thanks for suggestion (y)

Comment: Hm yes then I dont know it sry.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use backend for that ***for eg***:if you are using php and mysql use this code:

```
<?php include "db.php">
<div id="main-content">
    <h2>Add New Record</h2>
    <form class="post-form" action="savedata.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="sname" />
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="sphone" />
        </div>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Save"  />
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this should be after you create a database (i created in db.php)
 hope it helps :)